# Postgres 9.6.x: how to auto-update secondary table from primary table?

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a small quiz app where I want to keep track of how many times each question is answered correctly and incorrectly. There are three tables: Questions, Playthrus, and AnswerCounts. In the Playthrus table, I capture (1) `incorrect_answer`, which is the Primary Key **int** of the Question that ended the quiz due to a wrong answer; and (2) `correct_answers`, which is an **array** of Primary Keys of Questions answered correctly.

AnswerCounts table has three columns: `id`, `correct_count`, and `incorrect_count`. `id` maps to Questions table ids.

My question is: how can I setup my postgres database such that, whenever a new row is submitted to Playthrus table, (1) create or update row for all the Primary Keys found in the `incorrect_answer` and `correct_answers` columns; and (2) `correct_count` and `incorrect_count` increment accordingly?

Alternatively, am I approaching this issue incorrectly and there is a better methodology altogether?

I'm using Postgres 9.6.3 and Sequelize.

---

Edit: Per response below, I ditched the increment trigger and created a new table, Answers.

```
CREATE TABLE answers(
  id serial primary key,
  question_id int REFERENCES questions (id),
  playthru_id int REFERENCES playthrus (id),
  was_correct boolean
);
```

I update this table with all answers, correct and incorrect, from a given playthru.

Query for determining question answered correctly the most and incorrectly the most:

```
SELECT id
    FROM questions
    WHERE id in (
        SELECT question_id
        FROM answers
        GROUP BY question_id
        ORDER BY COUNT(CASE WHEN [NOT] was_correct THEN 1 END) <--
    DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalisation rules would say you should ditch the "correct answers" array in favour of a separate table, one row per answer. This could reference the primary key of the "playthru", the primary key of the question, and a boolean "was correct" column. This also leaves room for additional data you can't capture in your current design, such as the actual answer given, or maybe even how long they spent on the question, etc.

You can get back your existing array in a select query using the `array_agg` function, and even join through to the full questions and get an array of their text rather than just IDs.

Importantly, you can then calculate your correct and incorrect counts on the fly as well: group by question ID and "was correct", and output a count (*). To get both correct and incorrect on one row for easier processing, you can use a case statement like this:

```
SELECT
    question_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN was_correct THEN 1 END) as correct_answers,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN NOT was_correct THEN 1 END) as incorrect_answers
FROM playthru_questions
GROUP BY question_id
```

The trick here is that COUNT ignores the nulls where the CASE doesn't match, and counts the rows that match the condition.

Comment: I like where you're going with this rationale. I'll post my resolution once I work it out in full. One remaining issue I'd want to resolve, though, is how to retrieve the "wrongiest" and "rightiest" questions: the question with the most correct and incorrect answers, respectively. Perhaps new columns on the Questions table?... though my initial thought was to keep that table pure and unchanging.

Comment: @Kwhitejr That's easy: `ORDER BY COUNT(CASE WHEN NOT was_correct THEN 1 END) DESC LIMIT 1`. Until you hit some really critical performance issue, there should be no need to store anything that can be calculated from the raw data; that's the beauty of relational database design.

Comment: Many thanks. If I can impose one last time, how can I add the count made by your suggested line (see arrowed line in edited question) to the query result? As the `COUNT` of `was_correct` entries from Answers table is not available in Questions table, not sure how to get this number without an entirely separate query. I messed around with `WITH` and `JOIN` but couldn't get the desired count together with the question id.

Comment: @Kwhitejr I suggest you look for a general introduction to SQL joins somewhere online, but basically you want something like `... FROM questions AS q INNER JOIN answers AS a ON q.id = a.question_id ...`

Answer (score 1):

Check out `CREATE TRIGGER` in postgresql doc.